# removing a row by a string in it within an OBJECT in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data and trying to remove all rows where I have `"!ENDMSG!"` in the `dateTime` column

```
                   dateTime  tradePrice  tradeVolume  aggVolume     bid1     ask1  quote_counter
33501  2017-09-19 15:59:53     12545.5          1.0    54344.0  12545.0  12545.5      1567101.0
33502  2017-09-19 15:59:59     12545.0          1.0    54345.0  12545.0  12545.5      1567136.0
33503  2017-09-19 16:00:00     12545.0          1.0    54346.0  12544.5  12545.0      1567146.0
33504  2017-09-19 16:03:44     12544.0         17.0    54363.0  12544.0  12544.0      1567519.0
33505             !ENDMSG!         NaN          NaN        NaN      NaN      NaN            NaN
```

The problem is that the type of the `dateTime` column is `object` and therefore **ALL** the following options fail:

```
df[df.dateTime.str.contains('!ENDMSDG!') == False]
df[~df.dateTime.str.contains("!")]
df = df[~df['dateTime'].str.contains('!ENDMSDG!')]
print(df[df['dateTime'].str.match('!ENDMSDG!')])#another try to catch it
```

Comment: Hmm, for `ENDMSDG` it seems typo, but `df[~df['dateTime'].str.contains('!')]` for me working nice.

Comment: "fail" is not very clear.  For example, the only one of your options which _should_ have worked -- the only one without a typo -- is `df[~df.dateTime.str.contains("!")]`, but you didn't show what the output was, so it's hard to know if you just forgot to bind the result to something or if something else is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems need change `!ENDMSDG!` to `!ENDMSG!` (not second `D` letter):

```
df = df[~df['dateTime'].str.contains('!ENDMSG!')]

df = df[~df['dateTime'].str.contains('!')]
#alternative with disable regex
#df = df[~df['dateTime'].str.contains('!', regex=False)]
```

If need check start of string:

```
df = df[~df['dateTime'].str.startswith('!')]

print (df)
                  dateTime  tradePrice  tradeVolume  aggVolume     bid1  \
33501  2017-09-19 15:59:53     12545.5          1.0    54344.0  12545.0   
33502  2017-09-19 15:59:59     12545.0          1.0    54345.0  12545.0   
33503  2017-09-19 16:00:00     12545.0          1.0    54346.0  12544.5   
33504  2017-09-19 16:03:44     12544.0         17.0    54363.0  12544.0   

          ask1  quote_counter  
33501  12545.5      1567101.0  
33502  12545.5      1567136.0  
33503  12545.0      1567146.0  
33504  12544.0      1567519.0
```

Comment: If this is the issue, why didn't we vote to close as a typo, exactly?

Comment: @DSM - Because not sure why `df = df[~df['dateTime'].str.contains('!')]` does not work.